# How do I fix this version error?

Tags: 8, drush, updating

I have a Drupal 8 site that has been installed with Composer. Last week, I updated Search API 1.14 and Search API Solr 3.7.

The module are in the good version, but when I run `drush updatedb`, the following error appears.

> [error] Search API Solr requiert ce module et cette version. Vous
>   utilisez actuellement Search API version (Currently using Dépendance
>   non résolue Search API (Version >=8.x-1.14 requise))

> [error] Search API Solr requires this module and this version. You are
>   currently using Search API version (Currently using Unresolved
>   Dependency Search API (Version> = 8.x-1.14 Required))

I checked the installed version and it is the last one. How can I fix this error?

The content of the composer.json file is the following.

```
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.14",
    "drupal/search_api_autocomplete": "^1.0",
    "drupal/search_api_location": "^1.0",
    "drupal/search_api_solr": "^3.6",
```

Comment: Have you run the composer update command after updating the versions in your composer.json?

Comment: @AnsonWHan yes and this has updated to the latest versions

Comment: Sometimes deleting the whole vendor folder and running `composer install` again might help

Comment: @IsmailCherri Is it safe? Should he just do `sudo rm -R /vendor` ?

Comment: @IsmailCherri Do you have to `composer install` or `composer update --with-dependencies` ?

Comment: It is safe, I usually do `composer install`

Comment: @IsmailCherri Thank you it works ;-) I check to see if it did not break anything.